# Gimp: How to remove those line with GIMP?

Tags: gimp, png

How to remove those lines (I dont know what those line named) from the PNG image using GIMP. I am very new to GIMP.

[image: My Image]

Comment: Individual people who sell their images image stocker companies often insert something difficult to remove to their images to make using the image without paying difficult. Image stockers often include their logo, not only lines. The contrast is low to make possible to evaluate the value of the image and to prevent simply selecting the lines and applying something like "content aware delete" or manual cleaning by copying fitting content from somewhere near. If you help someone else to use copyrighted stuff without a license you participate the offence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the Magic Wand (Fuzzy Select Tool) to select blocks of colour. You may need to adjust the threshold in the Tool Options to get a good selection
2. Then sample the colour you want using the Eyedropper tool
3. Do *Edit > Fill with FG colour*.
4. Repeat for different areas of the image.

If there are areas that can't be easily selected you may need to use the Paint Brush tool to manually paint out the lines. Sorry there's no automatic way to fix this.

Note: If you had access to the original layered XCF, and the lines were on their own layer, you could just delete the layer. PNGs don't have layers so this isn't an option.

Comment: 3rd steps just unavailable

Comment: @KopiBryant No, I tested the steps listed. It definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

With `Filters>Blur>Selective Gaussian blur`, radius around 60 on your image:

[image]

Notice that it blurred out the diagonal lines,  but hardly blurred the barcode, your red circle, or the checkerboard pattern.

Caution: this is fairly CPU intensive, wait for it to finish before pronouncing it dead:)